# Why do i need to add repeat to make it display?

Tags: html, css

here is my [page](http://dev.posnation.com/build_system/systemconfig.php?id=7&step=1)

here is my CSS

```
dot {
 background:url("images/non_selected.png") repeat scroll 22px 22px transparent;
 height:22px;
 width:22px;
}
```

when i change it to

```
 url("images/non_selected.png") norepeat scroll 22px 22px transparent
```

nothing displays...what gives

Answer (score 4):

it's `no-repeat` not `norepeat`. let me know if that doesn't fix it.

edit #1: you are offsetting it too much...try

```
background: url(http://dev.posnation.com/build_system/css/images/non_selected.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
```

Comment: its still not displaying take a look

Comment: Change the `22px 22px` to `0 0`

Comment: last part is do you know why its not aligned with the text....vertical_align middle is not working

Comment: haven't tested this, but the property should be `vertical-align` with a dash, not an underscore.

Comment: Try adjusting the last `0px` to be `50%` or something.

Comment: It's aligning the background image vertically to 50%, which is the middle of the list item's space.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you've offset the background image by 22 pixels.  The image starts outside of the range of `dot`, so it doesn't show up unless you repeat it.  Instead, try:

```
background: url("images/non_selected.png") no-repeat scroll left top;
```

The important part is changing "22px 22px" to "left top".